# Refresh access token failed with status code: 401

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to test botframework server on my localhost. 
I followed the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-3-enable-security-and-test-on-localhost- .

First I changed app config with the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword passed the test of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-2 .
Then I started my bot on localhost and the web page shows it was running on http://localhost:3979/ .
But when I tried to test it on the Bot Framework Emulator, it returned 400 directline.postActivity with the message of "Refresh access token failed with status code: 401".

The screenshot is on https://i.loli.net/2019/06/06/5cf88ea120b9973175.png .

My botframework version is 3.13.1.
My Bot Framework Emulator version is 4.3.3.

What should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks for any help.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "Refresh access token failed with status code: 401"
  }
}
```

```
[11:42:22]POST 201 directline.start Conversation
[11:42:22]Emulator listening on http://localhost:49840
[11:42:22]ngrok listening on https://082d32c4.ngrok.io
[11:42:22]ngrok traffic inspector:http://127.0.0.1:4040
[11:42:22]Will bypass ngrok for local addresses
[11:42:25]->message hi
[11:42:26]POST 400 directline.postActivity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Refresh access token failed with status code: 401"` errors are almost always an issue with appId/appPass.

Please verify:

1. You have the correct appId/appPass from the [App Registration Portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade)

[image]

[image]

*Note: If you didn't save your password, just click "New client secret" to generate a new one.*

2. Verify you set the correct appId/appPass in `web.config`

[image]

3. Verify that you entered the correct app/Id/appPass in Emulator:

[image]

---

You should also [upgrade Emulator to the latest release](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases). There was a bug in Emulator long before 4.3.3 that caused this error, but I guess there could be something similar with V3 bots, since we rarely use them.

If this is a new bot, you should really be using [V4](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples). V3 will be deprecated July 1, 2019. Existing bots will work, but users will no longer be able to create them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It could work after I update the Emulator to 4.3.3. But currently, I have an unauthorized problem. The screenshot showed as follow.

![屏幕快照 2019-06-12 08.21.53.png](https://i.loli.net/2019/06/12/5d0045aabd60541903.png)

Do you know how this issue cause?

Thank you!

Comment: 401 errors, which you're still getting, are still usually appId/appPassword related. If you can share your code (like in a GitHub repo), I might be able to troubleshoot more. What's your appId?